# Running two separate (non-nested) for loops within one CSV file

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I am currently trying to create a config template using CSV rows and columns as variable output into a text file for one of my network configurations. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv

with open('VRRP Mapping.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    myfile = open('VRRP fix.txt', 'w')
    next(reader, None)
    myfile.write('*' * 50 + '\n' + 'VLAN interfaces for Core A\n' + '*' * 50 + '\n\n')
    for row in reader:
        #First, for the A side
        myfile.write('interface vlan ' + str(row[0]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('no ip vrrp ' + str(row[7]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' ' + row[9] + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' adver-int 10\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' backup-master enable\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' holddown-timer 60\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' priority ' + str(row[3]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' enable\n')
        myfile.write('exit\n\n')
    myfile.write('*' * 50 + '\n' + 'VLAN interfaces for Core B\n' + '*' * 50 + '\n\n')
    for row in reader:
        #And then the B side
        myfile.write('interface vlan ' + str(row[0]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('no ip vrrp ' + str(row[7]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' ' + row[9] + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' adver-int 10\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' backup-master enable\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' holddown-timer 60\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' priority ' + str(row[5]) + '\n')
        myfile.write('ip vrrp ' + str(row[8]) + ' enable\n')
        myfile.write('exit\n\n')
    myfile.close()
```

The problem I am having is after the first for loop. The 'VLAN interfaces for core b' shows up, but everything in the second for loop does not output to the text file at all.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to read the reader twice, you need to read the file twice.  Once you finish a book, you don't just keep reading and expect to find anything else.  You need to go back to the beginning.  To do that, use

```
f.seek(0)
next(reader, None)
```

between the `for` loops.  Note that `f` is a terrible name for a file object, as also is `myfile`.  They are not at all descriptive of what file it is or what the file is for.

Comment: `myfile` is the output file, `f` is the input file.

Comment: @Barmar: How could I have missed that?  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Also, I know f and myfile are both terrible, but this was something I was working out on the fly, so values were arbitrary to me.

Comment: @OfWolfAndMan: I'm happy to have helped.  The Stack Overflow way of showing your appreciation is to upvote the answers that you like, and to accept the one you like the most.  Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You have consumed all lines in your reader object and need to start from the beginning again. Before the second for loop add:

```
f.seek(0)
```

This will bring the pointer back to the beginning of the file so you can loop over it again. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm